# PHP Script works in curl but GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I have already checked this post but not working for me: [API request works with cURL but not with Guzzle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094874/api-request-works-with-curl-but-not-with-guzzle)

## **PHP Script to access token works perfectly for me**

**Initialization**

```
$_consumerKey = "consumer key";
$method = "POST";   
$endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
$callbackUrl = "https://localhost/script/test.php";

$authorizationParams = array(
    'oauth_callback' => $callbackUrl,
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $_consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5( microtime() . mt_rand() ),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);
```

**Prepare Signature**

```
function getSignature( $method, $endpoint, $authorizationParams, $urlParams = array() ) {
    $authorizationParams = array_merge( $authorizationParams, $urlParams );
    uksort( $authorizationParams, 'strcmp' );
    foreach ( $authorizationParams as $key => $value ) {
        $authorizationParams[$key] = rawurlencode( $key ) . '=' . rawurlencode( $value );
    }
    $signatureBase = array(
        rawurlencode( $method ),
        rawurlencode( $endpoint ),
        rawurlencode( implode( '&', $authorizationParams ) ),
    );
    $signatureBaseString = implode( '&', $signatureBase );
    $signatureKey = array(
        rawurlencode("consumer token"),
        ""
    );
    $signatureKeyString = implode('&', $signatureKey);
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureBaseString, $signatureKeyString, true));
}
```

**convert array to string**

```
function getAuthorizationString( $authorizationParams ) {
    $authorizationString = 'Authorization: OAuth';
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $authorizationParams as $key => $value ) { // loop over authorization params array
        $authorizationString .= !$count ? ' ' : ', ';
        $authorizationString .= rawurlencode( $key ) . '="' . rawurlencode( $value ) . '"';
        $count++;
    }
    return $authorizationString;
}
$authorizationParams['oauth_signature'] = getSignature( $method, $endpoint, $authorizationParams );
$apiParams = array(
    'method' => $method,
    'endpoint' => $endpoint,
    'authorization' => getAuthorizationString( $authorizationParams )
);
```

**Curl Request**

```
$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $apiParams['endpoint'],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        $apiParams['authorization'],
        'Expect:'
    )
);
$curlOptions[CURLOPT_POST] = TRUE;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curlOptions );
$apiResponse = curl_exec( $ch );
print_r($apiResponse);
```

**Now when I try to replace curl with Guzzle Http, I get following error. Notice the error details, It said callback url is not same as registered in app. But I am using same callback url and same was used in CURL**

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
> error: `POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token` resulted in
> a `403 Forbidden` response: Callback URL not approved
> for this client application. A (truncated...) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\script\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\script\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69):
> GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\script\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204):
> GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\script\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153):
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1,
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\script\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48):
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\script\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php
> on line 113

## **Curl Code does not work for me**

**Initialization**

```
include "vendor/autoload.php";

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$_consumerKey = "consumer id";
$method = "POST";   
$endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
$callbackUrl = "https://localhost/test.php";    
$authorizationParams = array(
    'oauth_callback' => $callbackUrl,
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $_consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5( microtime() . mt_rand() ),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_version' => '1.0'
);
```

**Signature Creation**

```
function getSignature( $method, $endpoint, $authorizationParams, $urlParams = array() ) {
    $authorizationParams = array_merge( $authorizationParams, $urlParams );
    uksort( $authorizationParams, 'strcmp' );
    foreach ( $authorizationParams as $key => $value ) {
        $authorizationParams[$key] = rawurlencode( $key ) . '=' . rawurlencode( $value );
    }
    $signatureBase = array(
        rawurlencode( $method ),
        rawurlencode( $endpoint ),
        rawurlencode( implode( '&', $authorizationParams ) ),
    );
    $signatureBaseString = implode( '&', $signatureBase );
    $signatureKey = array(
        rawurlencode("consumer secret"),
        ""
    );
    $signatureKeyString = implode('&', $signatureKey);
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureBaseString, $signatureKeyString, true));
}
```

**Conversion of array to string**

```
function getAuthorizationString( $authorizationParams ) {
    $authorizationString = '';
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $authorizationParams as $key => $value ) { // loop over authorization params array
        $authorizationString .= !$count ? ' ' : ', ';
        $authorizationString .= rawurlencode( $key ) . '="' . rawurlencode( $value ) . '"';
        $count++;
    }
    return $authorizationString;
}
$authorizationParams['oauth_signature'] = getSignature( $method, $endpoint, $authorizationParams );
$apiParams = array(
    'method' => $method,
    'endpoint' => $endpoint,
    'authorization' => getAuthorizationString( $authorizationParams ),
    'url_params' => array()
);
```

**Guzzle Http request**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', $apiParams['endpoint'], [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        "Authorization" => "OAuth " . $apiParams['authorization']
    ]
]);
$result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: From your code, `$apiParams['authorization']` has already contained **"Authorization: OAuth"**

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAuthorizationString( $authorizationParams ) {
    $authorizationString = 'Authorization: OAuth';
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $authorizationParams as $key => $value ) { // loop over authorization params array
        $authorizationString .= !$count ? ' ' : ', ';
        $authorizationString .= rawurlencode( $key ) . '="' . rawurlencode( $value ) . '"';
        $count++;
    }
    return $authorizationString;
}
```

The return value from this function is `Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="https://localhost/script/test.php", oauth_consumer_key="consumer key", ....`

```
'authorization' => getAuthorizationString( $authorizationParams )
```

Then you assign it to `$apiParams['authorization']`

```
"Authorization" => "OAuth " . $apiParams['authorization']
```

Finally it concatenates to the header, now you get `Authorization => OAuth Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="https://localhost/script/test.php", oauth_consumer_key="consumer key", ....` what is obviously invalid.

In conclusion `$authorizationString` need to be initialized with an empty string.

Comment: There is an extra space after `OAuth `, try to remove it. And in your CURL version the header is `Accept: application/json` but in the GuzzleHttp version the header becomes `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'`, `Except:` is also missed. Are you sure these values are correct?